# .vimrc "set pastetoggle=<F2>" giving error while running "source .vimrc"

Tags: vim, vi

I'm using CentOS 7 and added `set pastetoggle=<F2>` in `.vimrc` to toggle the auto-indentation.
While running `source .vimrc`, it is throwing the below error

```
-bash: .vimrc: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
-bash: .vimrc: line 4: `set pastetoggle=<F2>'
```

Here's my .vimrc file for reference

```
set ai
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
set pastetoggle=<F2>
```

Please help me and let me know, how to resolve the issue?

Comment: I'm not doing anything specifically with regards to bash. Is there any other way to execute a dot file in CentOS? Please help me understand.

Comment: So how do I make the changes getting effect in vim editor, without running the vim config? I believe the source command can be used to execute the config file. The same config executed fine using source command, without the pastetoggle config in .vimrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to source a vim config file in your shell, which would indeed throw an error. If you are trying to update the vim config on the go, then after updating your **~/.vimrc** file(assuming you are using vim to edit the vimrc file) , from vim open the command line mode by pressing <kbd>:</kbd> and type in <kbd>source %</kbd> (where % denotes current file). Then your new config gets updated on the go.

**If you're lazy like me then bind it to a key for sourcing, like so in normal mode :**

```
nnoremap <leader>so :w<cr>:source %<cr>
```

If you are using some other text editor to edit ~/.vimrc, then save and exit the file, then open a new instance of vim and your changes get updated automatically.

Comment: Thank you @Yedhin.  Follwed your steps and It's working fine.